# How do I change my MYSQL timezone to be permanent Pacific time?

Tags: mysql, database, time

so that when I do now(), it will show the current California time?

Comment: Please edit your question to detail which OS your server runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOW() returns the current time and timezone as currently understood by the server.  If it is not returning the current time in PST, it will be the server that needs changed not MySQL.

[MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)